# Windows 8 RT, load html files from InstalledLocation not working

Tags: windows-8, webview, windows-runtime

I'm developing a windows 8 app using C#. I need to load a html page that is downloaded on runtime to this path:

C:\Users\Me\Desktop\SVNWORKING\MyApp\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\myweb.html

And I load the page in a WebView using:

```
WebView2.Source = new Uri("ms-appx-web:///myweb.html");
```

When I test the app in the simulator or in my Surfaces (RT and PRO) while debugging the WebView loads the html page, but If I generate a package and install it or install the app from the Windows Store I can't see the html in the WebView. Permissions problem with releases?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're seeing this behavior because of the difference between debugging and a real app deployment. When an app is deployed for debugging purposes, it's running from a different location than a Store deployment. In the latter case, the install folder is actually read-only.

Thus when you say "downloaded on runtime," a Store-deployed app will not be able to save a file to InstalledLocation at all. You can test this by creating your app package and then using the PowerShell script to do the deployment. This does the same as the Store deployment, and means that the app won't be in the Debug location as you have above.

You need to use your app data folders instead of InstalledLocation, that is, either Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.LocalFolder or TemporaryFolder, and then use ms-appdata:///local or ms-appdata:///temp as the uri base. Note, however, that this is supported starting with Windows 8.1 only, not Windows 8.0.